# Subtracting values from a value equal to specific date

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks similar to:

| Date | Total_Nonfarm | Leisure_and_Hospitality |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 300 | 50 |
| 2020-02-01 | 200 | 40 |
| 2020-03-01 | 100 | 15 |
| 2020-04-01 | 75 | 15 |
| 2020-05-01 | 150 | 10 |

I need to calculate the monthly losses of both Nonfarm and Leisure and Hospitality jobs (two new columns) based on the total amount lost since 2020-02-01. So this would not affect rows before 2020-02-01, only after.

I've tried finding a way to print the value for the jobs dependent on date being equal to 2020-02-01, but could not successfully figure it out. I thought perhaps if I could print this value (say `Feb2020 <- *the correct function to find that value*`, then I could use dplyr to mutate a new column and execute `mutate(Total_jobs_lost = Feb2020 - Total_Nonfarm`. But I think this would then affect rows prior to 2020-02-01.

I would like the output to look as such:

| Date | Total_Nonfarm | Leisure_and_Hospitality | Total_Nonfarm_Losses | LH_Losses |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 | 300 | 50 | NA | NA |
| 2020-02-01 | 200 | 40 | 0 | 0 |
| 2020-03-01 | 100 | 15 | -100 | -25 |
| 2020-04-01 | 75 | 15 | -125 | -25 |
| 2020-05-01 | 150 | 10 | -50 | -30 |

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the desired output in a table form because your description is unclear

Comment: Thanks-- updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
  library(tidyverse)

data <- read.delim("clipboard")

data$Total_Nonfarm_Losses <- rep("NA", nrow(data))
data$LH_Losses <- rep("NA", nrow(data))

Feb2020 <- filter(data,Date == "2020-02-01")$Total_Nonfarm
Feb2020b <- filter(data,Date == "2020-02-01")$Leisure_and_Hospitality 

data[2:5,] <- data[2:5,] %>% 
  mutate(Total_Nonfarm_Losses = Total_Nonfarm- Feb2020,
         LH_Losses = Leisure_and_Hospitality - Feb2020b)
`  


            Date Total_Nonfarm Leisure_and_Hospitality Total_Nonfarm_Losses LH_Losses
1 2020-01-01           300                      50                   NA        NA
2 2020-02-01           200                      40                    0         0
3 2020-03-01           100                      15                 -100       -25
4 2020-04-01            75                      15                 -125       -25
5 2020-05-01           150                      10                  -50       -30
```

Answer (score 0):

```
require(tidyverse)
require(lubridate)
(df <- read_csv2(file = "data.csv"))

df$Date <- dmy(df$Date)
df$Total_Nonfarm_Losses <- NA
df$Leisure_and_Hospitality_Losses <- NA

timepoint <- ymd("2020/02/01")
(before <- df %>% filter(Date < timepoint))
(after <- df %>% filter(Date >= timepoint))

(
  after
  %>% mutate(Feb_Nonfarm = df[df$Date == timepoint, "Total_Nonfarm"] ,
             Feb_Leisure = df[df$Date == timepoint, "Leisure_and_Hospitality"],
            Total_Nonfarm_Losses = Feb_Nonfarm - Total_Nonfarm,
            Leisure_and_Hospitality_Losses = Feb_Leisure - Leisure_and_Hospitality
             )
  %>% select(1:5)
  %>% bind_rows(before, .)
)
```

And the output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
  Date       Total_Nonfarm Leisure_and_Hospi~ Total_Nonfarm_Losses~ Leisure_and_Hospitality_L~
  <date>             <dbl>              <dbl>                 <dbl>                      <dbl>
1 2020-01-01           300                 50                    NA                         NA
2 2020-02-01           200                 40                     0                          0
3 2020-03-01           100                 15                   100                         25
4 2020-04-01            75                 15                   125                         25
5 2020-05-01           150                 10                    50                         30
```